# aws-sdk v3 client.send not waiting

Tags: node.js, nestjs, aws-sdk-js

I am using @aws-sdk/client-s3 in a nestJs application that is running within docker.
I am looking to download a logo file from aws so I can put it in a PDF document.

When using await with send the code is not waiting for the send method to complete.

The code send code is run after the generateHeader has completed. It is not waiting for const data = await client.send(getCommand) to complete

```
import { GetObjectCommand, S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

private async generateHeader(doc: PDFKit.PDFDocument) {
  const client = new S3Client({});

  const getCommand = new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: this.configService.get('AWS_PUBLIC_BUCKET_NAME'),
    Key: this.configService.get('AWS_LOGO_KEY'),
  });

  try {
    const data = await client.send(getCommand);

    this.logger.warn(
      `in try block line 181 ${data.$metadata.httpStatusCode}`,
    );  
  } catch (error) {
    // error handling.
    const { requestId, cfId, extendedRequestId } = error.$$metadata;
    this.logger.log({ requestId, cfId, extendedRequestId });
    this.logger.log(`error name: ${error.name}`);
  } finally {
    this.logger.log('finally block');
  }

  this.logger.warn('after aws getCommand try block line 191');
}
```

Comment: Was about to throw in some thoughts then realized they didn't make sense, was just missing `async` and that's within a function because of the formatting, took the liberty to fix it, I've put the code in "```" (3 backticks) and added "ts" after the 3 opening backticks for proper highlighting, also fixed typo was -> aws.
Other than that can't help right now sorry